# Assign CSV serialisation of an object into a string variable in R

Tags: r, csv

I am writing a package that would create a CSV gists on github.com from a data frame. Signature would be like so:

`gist.csv(my.data.frame, public=FALSE, description="my results in CSV")`

I'm using `httr` for the HTTP calls and the GitHub API expects the content of the gist as part of the body.

However, I'm stuck on serialising the object `my.data.frame` into a CSV string and assigning the string into a variable. I'm looking for a way to have

`csv.string <- write.csv(my.data.table)`

Is there a good way to achieve that (ideally without having to resolve to writing to a temp file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write to a variable in R via a `textConnection`. For example

```
#sample data
dd <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=letters[1:10])

#write to variable
x <- ""
tx <- textConnection("x","w")
write.csv(dd, tx)
close(tx)

#check contents
cat(x, sep="\n")
```